# Best way to pass kwargs to a thread runner method

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I'm developing a threaded data collector that queries storage devices.

I have the following thread runner method:

```
def threadrunner(cfg, filer, APPLIANCES, kwargs):

    _client  = login(cfg, filer)
    _filer   = DeviceConfig(_client, Version=True)
    APPLIANCES.append(_filer)
```

And the code that calls it:

```
    newthr = threading.Thread(target=threadrunner, args=(cfg, appliance, APPLIANCES, kwargs))
    newthr.name = appliance
    newthr.start()
```

What is the best way to pass a variable list of **kwargs to threadrunner()? In the example above Version=True is one version of a kwarg I need to pass. All kwargs that I need to pass are simple True|False toggles.

Comment: i don't see your problem. `kwargs` in `threadrunner` should be a dict then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `kwargs` keyword

You could do something like this:

```
def threadrunner(*args, **kwargs):

    _client  = login(*args)
    if 'APPLIANCES' not in kwargs:
        raise ValueError('Appliances not in kwargs')
    APPLIANCES = kwargs.pop('APPLIANCES', None)

    #Assuming your boolean values go here.
    _filer   = DeviceConfig(_client, **kwargs)
    APPLIANCES.append(_filer)

newthr = threading.Thread(target=threadrunner, args=(cfg, appliance,) kwargs={'APPLIANCES': APPLIANCES, 'boolkey1':boolval1, ....)
newthr.name = appliance
newthr.start()
```